# Constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, oop

```
class A{
    A(String s){
        System.out.println("New A" + s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
} 
class B{
    B(String s){
        System.out.println("New B" + s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
class C extends A{
    C(String s){
        System.out.println("New C" + s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

error on line 28, "C(String s){"

I was following the step by step for a practice for a class. Very confused. Thank you so much for helping with this dumb question.

Comment: The constructor of `C` is taken care of with `A`'s constructor because `C` extends `A` (unless you'd like to override it for different functionality). Also it wouldn't be "New B" for `C` it should be "New A" (should be taken care of by fixing your constructor)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because C extends A. In order to properly extend, you also need to invoke a constructor for A. The only constructor for A available is `A(String s)`. The following should work:

```
C(String s){
    super(s); // calls new A(s)
    System.out.println("New B" + s);
}
```

Basically, when you are making a constructor in a subclass (C in this case), it will need to invoke a superclass constructor to set up the "part of the object" that corresponds to A (for lack of better terms). When you do not make an explicit call to a superclass constructor, it will automatically call `super()` without any parameters--which works *only if there is a constructor `A()`*. <sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> This is complicated by the fact that if you do not make a constructor at all in the superclass, it will actually have an *implicit* constructor that reads as follows: `public A() {}`, meaning that it takes no arguments and does nothing in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can add default constructors in both of your classes A & C like

```
public class A{
    public A(){}
    public A(String s){
        System.out.println("New A" + s);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

   }
} 
class C extends A{
    public C(){}
    public C(String s){
        System.out.println("New C" + s);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
   }
}
```